# Java how to use an image within a jar file

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I was making a game using a JFrame that would load an image to be displayed. Then when I tried to run the program, it didn't find the image in the jar. So, how do you retrieve a file from within a jar? Is it `/img.png` or `img.png` or even `\\img.png`? I just don't know how paths in java work yet.

(Edit) Figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

/img.png is correct.  How are you attempting to load it?  You need to use a classloader which knows about that JAR file to get at the image file.

Try this method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Try something like this, assuming the JAR file is in your classpath.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream is = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/img.png");
        // read in the data stream
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using an image icon. so it would be like this: ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/img.png");

Comment: @HarrisonBergeron No, it would `ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img.png"));` - Passing a `String` to `ImageIcon` will assume that the value is a file reference, which it is not

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, it would only be like that if it was in the jar file?

Comment: I mistakenly wrote getResourceAsString instead of getResurceAsStream.  Corrected.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The imageicon thing you told me makes java have and exception

Comment: @HarrisonBergeron if you are trying to load the image for a static reference, then you need to use the Class more directly. Using the example above, it would be Myclass.class.getClassloader().getResource(...) instead

Answer (score 0):

For example,this is the jar file structure

[image: Jar File Stucture]

Make sure the jar is in the class path, then coding like this

```
String file01="tom.txt";
String file02="com/paic/jerry.txt";  
InputStream tom=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file01);
InputStream jerry=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file02);
```

Comment: Oh because I had heard if an image was in a jar file it would be "/tom.txt"

Comment: I think the "/" is not needed if you put the file at the root inside jar file

Comment: Oooh I though it was the other way around.